# Keep certain columns in a pandas DataFrame, deleting everything else

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a data table

```
    1  2  3  4  5  6 ..  n
A   x  x  x  x  x  x ..  x
B   x  x  x  x  x  x ..  x
C   x  x  x  x  x  x ..  x
```

And I want to slim it down so that I only have, say, columns 3 and 5 deleting all other and maintaining the structure. How could I do this with pandas? I think I understand how to delete a single column, but I don't know how to save a select few and delete all others.

Comment: More (faster) options along with timings are available in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54315757/4909087).

Answer (score 118, accepted):

If you have a list of columns you can just select those:

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]:
   1  2  3  4  5  6
A  x  x  x  x  x  x
B  x  x  x  x  x  x
C  x  x  x  x  x  x

In [12]: col_list = [3, 5]

In [13]: df = df[col_list]

In [14]: df
Out[14]:
   3  5
A  x  x
B  x  x
C  x  x
```

Comment: @andyhayden how about deleting all columns except the `n`th column (without using the column naming),

Comment: The issue with this answer, i.e. with the `df = df[cols_keep]` approach, is that it creates a slice of the dataframe. To prove this, see `df._is_copy` which will note a weakref to the parent dataframe. The slice can go on to cause `SettingWithCopyWarning` in subsequent operations.

In contrast, `df.drop(columns=df.columns.difference(cols_keep), inplace=True)` has no such issue.

Answer (score 29):

> ### How do I keep certain columns in a pandas DataFrame, deleting everything else?

The answer to this question is the same as the answer to "How do I delete certain columns in a pandas DataFrame?" Here are some additional options to those mentioned so far, along with timings.

#### **[`DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)**

One simple option is selection, as mentioned by in other answers,

```
# Setup.
df
   1  2  3  4  5  6
A  x  x  x  x  x  x
B  x  x  x  x  x  x
C  x  x  x  x  x  x

cols_to_keep = [3,5]
```

```
df[cols_to_keep]

   3  5
A  x  x
B  x  x
C  x  x
```

Or,

```
df.loc[:, cols_to_keep]

   3  5
A  x  x
B  x  x
C  x  x
```

---

#### **[`DataFrame.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html)** with `axis=1` or `'columns'` (0.21+)

However, we also have `reindex`, in recent versions you specify `axis=1` to drop:

```
df.reindex(cols_to_keep, axis=1)
# df.reindex(cols_to_keep, axis='columns')

# for versions < 0.21, use
# df.reindex(columns=cols_to_keep)

   3  5
A  x  x
B  x  x
C  x  x
```

On older versions, you can also use `reindex_axis`: `df.reindex_axis(cols_to_keep, axis=1)`.

---

#### **[`DataFrame.drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)**

Another alternative is to use `drop` to select columns by [`pd.Index.difference`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.difference.html):

```
# df.drop(cols_to_drop, axis=1)
df.drop(df.columns.difference(cols_to_keep), axis=1)

   3  5
A  x  x
B  x  x
C  x  x
```

---

### **Performance**

[image]

The methods are roughly the same in terms of performance; `reindex` is faster for smaller N, while `drop` is faster for larger N. The performance is relative as the Y-axis is logarithmic.

**Setup and Code**

```
import pandas as pd
import perfplot

def make_sample(n):
    np.random.seed(0)
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.full((n, n), 'x'))
    cols_to_keep = np.random.choice(df.columns, max(2, n // 4), replace=False)

    return df, cols_to_keep 

perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: make_sample(n),
    kernels=[
        lambda inp: inp[0][inp[1]],
        lambda inp: inp[0].loc[:, inp[1]],
        lambda inp: inp[0].reindex(inp[1], axis=1),
        lambda inp: inp[0].drop(inp[0].columns.difference(inp[1]), axis=1)
    ],
    labels=['__getitem__', 'loc', 'reindex', 'drop'],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(2, 13)],
    xlabel='N',   
    logy=True,
    equality_check=lambda x, y: (x.reindex_like(y) == y).values.all()
)
```

Answer (score 12):

You could reassign a new value to your `DataFrame`, `df`:

```
df = df.loc[:,[3, 5]]
```

As long as there are no other references to the original `DataFrame`, the old `DataFrame` will get garbage collected.

Note that when using `df.loc`, the index is specified by *labels*. Thus above `3` and `5` are not ordinals, they represent the label names of the columns. If you wish to specify the columns by ordinal index, use `df.iloc`.

Answer (score 4):

For those who are searching an method to do this inplace:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
from typing import Set, Any
def remove_others(df: DataFrame, columns: Set[Any]):
    cols_total: Set[Any] = set(df.columns)
    diff: Set[Any] = cols_total - columns
    df.drop(diff, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

This will create the complement of all the columns in the dataframe and the columns which should be removed. Those can safely be removed. Drop works even on an empty set.

```
>>> df = DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3],"b":[2,3,4],"c":[3,4,5]})
>>> df
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  2  3  4
2  3  4  5

>>> remove_others(df, {"a","b","c"})
>>> df
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  2  3  4
2  3  4  5

>>> remove_others(df, {"a"})
>>> df
   a
0  1
1  2
2  3

>>> remove_others(df, {"a","not","existent"})
>>> df
   a
0  1
1  2
2  3
```

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is to use [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html):

```
In [5]: df.filter([3, 5])
Out[5]: 
   3  5
A  x  x
B  x  x
C  x  x
```